# Global ilumination Qt3D

Tags: qt, qt3d

How can I disable ilumination and shadowing effects and just use global ilumination in all the Qt3D scene? I've only found this at the documentation: https://doc.qt.io/qt3dstudio/lights.html and it seems like there are three types of lightning: points, directional and area, but not a way of just drawing items using his default color.

Comment: It's unclear what you want to achieve. You want to display a 3D object without any lights in the scene? In this case, if the object doesn't have a texture but only one color (e.g. red) you won't see any structure in the object, it will be a completely uniform red patch with the outline of the object. Is that what you want? If you have an object with a texture you can use [`QTextureMaterial`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt3dextras-qtexturematerial.html) which renders the object with an unlit texture.

Comment: @FlorianBlume i want to see a uniform red patch.

Comment: Two ideas: Use [`QTextureMaterial`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt3dextras-qtexturematerial.html) and as texture a 1x1 image with the color you want to apply on the model. That should give the model the same color everywhere (without guarantee, I've never tried this). You could also implement your own shader for your own material. That's a bit more complicated but if you check out the source code for the existing shaders it should become clear pretty quickly how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Florian Blume, I found that creating a useless light source is a good workaround. [Disable all light sources in Qt 3d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57216503/disable-all-light-sources-in-qt-3d)